# How can I do a Custom QueryInterface for .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, interop, queryinterface

I have .NET Assembly exposed to COM, and I want to create a custom QueryInterface, otherwise my Class will have to implement a lot of interfaces.

Currently my implementation is like this

```
[ComVisible(true]
[ProgId("SomeLib.SomeClass")]
[Guid("516E4529-38F1-44EE-B340-ABFA498DC922")]
public class MyClass : Interface1, Interface2......, etc
```

I want my class not to implement those interfaces, but when QueryInterface is called to return an object that implements the requested interface. I know this feature exists for .NET framework 4.0 (see [ICustomQueryInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustomqueryinterface.aspx) ) Unfortunately I need to do it in 3.5

Comment: You can't, IUnknown is implemented by the CLR.  Patching the v-table is too creepy.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from .NET 4.0, you *can* do this.
You can use [ICustomQueryInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustomqueryinterface.aspx) for this. See also a [usage sample](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/32350) and [another sample](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/35739).